# Different ways to traverse arrays in RISC-V

Tags: arrays, assembly, riscv

I'm currently learning about basic assembly language via RISC-V, and I'm slightly confused on valid ways to loop through an array.

If we're given a0 as a pointer to an integer array, would this suffice to move to the next element?

- lw s0, 0(a0) #pointer to array is stored in s0
- lw s0 4(s0) #call this each time you want to move to the next element?

If I would want to modify the actual value of the element at the location as well, can I simply use sw?

I also know using slli/srli also allows you to shift, can anyone explain that concept?

Thank you!

Comment: Let's take your thought to the logical extreme: what if the array is a a thousand elements long?  Are you going to write a different `lw` to access each element?  Rather impractical, no?  Instead, you want  to increment the pointer variable itself, and use a loop.

Comment: No, `lw s0, 4(s0)` doesn't increment s0, it dereferences `4+s0`.  You'd use that to go through a *linked list* where the `.next` member was the 2nd word.

Comment: Shifting is really a different topic and is better put into a different question. Although a web search with the query `bit shifting` should turn enough material that explains the concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic pattern for traversing an array (with n elements) is this:

1. store the array start address in register X
2. store the address after the last element in register Y (e.g. `Y = X + n * 4`) with shift and add instructions
3. dereference X (i.e. `lw` to load the word from the address that is present in X) and do something with that array element
4. increment X by word size (e.g. 4 bytes) with an `add` instruction
5. branch to step 3. if X is still less than Y
6. traversal is done

Regarding modification: You modify the loaded array element in a register and then you can store the new register value back into your array with `sw`.